# Implementing a slide-out menu bar after a login screen in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sidebar, xcode-storyboard

I have been following the appcoda tutorial (http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) on how to implement a slide-out menu bar for my app using SWRevealViewController. I am wanting to show the slide out menu after the user has logged in.

My root view is the login page. I created a reveal view controller like the tutorial, and put it after the login page. However, when I get to my root view, it displays a back button instead of my slide out bar. In the console, I am getting errors such as "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted." and "nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar".

I have attached an image of my storyboard. Would I need to implement another navigation controlller in the storyboard? [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you navigate from your login View controller to `SWRevealViewController`, you should hide the navigation bar, which covers the other navigation bar inside `SWRevealViewController`.

What I did is to hide the first navigation controller's navigation bar in `prepareForSegue` function of login page controller.

Comment: I just did this, it's hiding the navigation bar in the table view controller, though

Comment: `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}`, how did you do it?

Comment: that's the same method I'm using =/ it seems to just keep hiding all the bars after the SWRevealcontroller

Comment: See the [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7syg4cgjvm9sg32/SidebarDemo%202.zip?dl=0) which worked for me.

Comment: I've been following this, its a good tutorial. The only problem is it doesn't have a login screen, so my root view isn't what I want behind the slide out menu. Do you have a login screen before your slide out menu page?

Comment: Oh! sorry I opened the wrong file. I will look into this one thanks!